# Using simulations to prove E[Y] formula of a log normal distribution

Tags: r, distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

Assume that  $X∼ N (μ, σ^2)$ and that $Y = e^X$ and we have set $μ = 0$ and $σ = 1.5$. We have to prove that $E[Y] = e^{(μ+σ^2)/2}$ using 10000 simulations. I.e. `rnorm(n=10000,mean=0,sd=1.5)`. I have simulated values of $X$ using rnorm, but how can I use these values to make simulations of $Y$?

Comment: The answer is right in your question: $Y=\exp(X)$. You could also work with `rlnorm` directly.

Comment: Well, E[Y] = $e^{(μ+σ^2)/2}$ = $e^{(1.5^2)/2}$ = 3.08. Is this correct? Using x<-rlnorm(10000,mean=0,sd=1.5)
mean(x)= 3.07. I am just confused because it is very far from the mean, 0.

Comment: The log normal $y$ is obtained when you exponentiate a normal (or equivalently, the log of such a r.v. is normal, whence the name) as stated in your Q. Its expected value $Y$ is also given in your question. Here, $\mu$ is the expected value of the normal r.v. $X$ that when exponentiated gives the log-normally distributed r.v. $Y$.

Comment: But when you exponentiate =0 it doesn't give the log-normally distributed r.v.

Comment: With a geometric mean $\sigma = 1.5$ you will need an enormous simulation to get anywhere close to the expected result.  Start with a much smaller value of $\sigma:$ less than $0.6$ is usually reasonable.  But your question is puzzling, because it contains its own answer: you have defined $Y$ as the exponential of $X,$ whence if you have simulated values of $X,$ you merely exponentiate them to produce simulated values of $Y.$  What are you really trying to ask?

Comment: Using x <- rnorm(10000,mean=0,sd=1.5) and then mean(x), I get a mean = 0.01. I then exponentiate it, and get Y = $e^X$, Y = $e^{0.01} =  1.01 $. When I exponentiate  1.01 I don't get anything close to E[Y] = (μ+σ2)/2 = (1.52)/2
 = 3.08. So my question is why my calculations are so far from the theoretical calculation?

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way round. You first have to exponentiate to get the log-normally distributed r.v. and then take the mean to estimate the expected value of the log-normal. As in `mean(exp(rnorm(n=10000,mean=0,sd=1.5)))`

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.